# Cannot find module "cordova/exec" in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to develop a project in typescript, but for it i need to run a library in javascript, the link for the library is that https://www.grabba.com/downloads/cordova/plugin.

When i try to run this library in with my code, the ionic 2 return the error above. I am trying to solve it per days, and already pass for all the integration javascript and typescript tutorials in the google. Would someone help me to run this library?

My codes follow bellow:

guarda-codigo.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
        import { GrabbaProxcard } from './com.grabba.cordova.plugin/www/grabba';

        declare var cordova: any;

        /*
          Generated class for the GuardaCodigo page.

          See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
          Ionic pages and navigation.
        */
        @Component({
          selector: 'page-guarda-codigo',
          templateUrl: 'guarda-codigo.html'
        })
        export class GuardaCodigoPage {

          constructor(public nav: NavController) {
              function acessaGrabba(value: number){
              let proxcard = new GrabbaProxcard();
                proxcard.prototype.registerCallback();
              }
          }

          ionViewDidLoad() {
            console.log('ionViewDidLoad GuardaCodigoPage');
          }

        }
```

guarda-codigo.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>GuardaCodigo</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content class="registration">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label> Codigo</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name = "Codigo"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
  <button ion-button onclick="acessaGrabba(2)">Trigger</button>
</ion-content>
```

Someone could help me please, i really need to solve this problem. I will be very grateful. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: It looks like the error is because of package.json. Please provide the package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow my package.json below

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",


"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "cordova": "^6.5.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.8.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "com.grabba.cordova.plugin",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Rollers Monitor: An Ionic project"
}
```

Thank you for your help.